# Combining users' scroll + animation css3/Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, css, scroll, parallax

First post on SO so far :)

I'm creating a parallax website combining css3 + javascript.

I followed [this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/12/behind-the-scenes-of-nike-better-world/) tutorial and I have to say that it gave me quite a grasp on the subject.

I was just wondering 2 things:

1. How do I translate the movement on the X axis?
2. **Most Important**: How can i combine users' scrolling with animations?

I've seen there is plenty of plugins out there, but I'd rather develop a solution myself without getting the code too heavy and complicated. Could you point me out some good resource, which will enlighten me on this technique?

Thank you guys!

EDITED on 17/09/12 at 14.14 (+1 GTM TIME)
In case someone would be interested, that should be the idea-code by which we would do the trick:

$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('section[data-type="example"]').scroll(function() {

```
// If the user scroll as much as we need, in this instance 750px
if (scrollTop() > '750px') {
  // switch its class from ".animation" to ".animated" 
  $(".animation").toggleClass("animated"); 
}
```

}); 
});

CSS Classes would be:
.animation { 
  width: 300px; 
  height: 300px: 
  -webkit-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease; 
  -moz-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease; 
  -o-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease; 
  -ms-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease; transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease; }

.animated { width: 400px; height: 400px; }

As we see, in ".animation" we would find the initial size and the animation, and in ".animated" we're going to print what we want to achieve.

This has been created thanks to the hints provided by @jfriend00. Unfortunately I havn't had the possibility to try it yet, so feel free to improve it. I wrote it here because it seems like someone is interested to this topic, and previously I posted it in a comment making it unreadable :)

Also, Jfriend00 told that .scrollTop() is a JQuery Method, not a plain function. How do you think it could be improved using plain JS?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my grammar error and for the noobness; I'm not English Native and I'm quite new with programming :)

Comment: Hmm +1, Lateral scrolling is one such example: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/05/lateral-on-scroll-sliding-with-jquery/ Check out the source. It's well written.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you're asking for help with.  Are you asking how you track the position of a scroll bar?   Once you have the scroll bar position, how do you want to apply that an animation?  There are millions of possible animations so how one applies a scroll position to an animation depends entirely on what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: @Ashwinkumar Thank you! I see what's going on there! I will try it out later on! Cheers! :)

Comment: @jfriend00 Let's say that for example, I want to combine the users' scroll to a transitional effect. So i.e. once the user has scrolled 750px, I want an object to appear with a fade transition. How do I link the scrolling factor with the animation?

I think that once there I could find out by myself how to add different animation :)

>>inb4 I'm a bit of a noob with JS
>>inb4 if you don't feel like to write the code and could point me out a good reference, that'd be cool as well :)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> Let's say that for example, I want to combine the users' scroll to a
>   transitional effect. So i.e. once the user has scrolled 750px, I want
>   an object to appear with a fade transition. How do I link the
>   scrolling factor with the animation?

This is one way to approach that specific example:

1. You would register an event listener for the scroll event.
2. In the scroll event handler, you would examine the current scroll position and decide if you wanted to take action (e.g. `scrollTop` is more than 750px).
3. The easiest way to trigger a CSS3 animation is to add a class name to your object.  If the object has CSS assigned to it for that new class and the object is configured for CSS transitions on any of the properties that are changed by adding the class name to the object, then a CSS3 animation will start when the class is added.

Comment: So if I write something like:

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('section[data-type="example"]').scroll(function() {
  if (scrollTop() > '750px')  {
    $(".animation").toggleClass("animated");
  }
});

CSS

.animation {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px:
  -webkit-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease; 
  -moz-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease; 
  -o-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease; 
  -ms-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease; 
  transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease; 
  }
.animated {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  }

That should do the magic, right?

Comment: Sorry I'm a noob I know :D I also cannot try the code until this evening, can't wait lol

Comment: @JohnFunk - please don't put multi-line code in comments.  It's completely unreadable.  If you must add more code, then add it onto the end of your question (where you can format it appropriately) and post a comment that points to it.  Your code looks like the general idea except that `.scrollTop()` is a jQuery method, not a plain function.

Comment: So sorry, really...it's the first time I post here, thanks for pointing me the right behavior without being rude, I really appreciate :)

Is there any JS function which I can call instead of .scrollTop()?

Comment: @JohnFunk - I don't know what exactly you're trying to do, but perhaps what you want is: `if $(this).scrollTop() > 750)`.  See [here in the jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) for more info.

Comment: What I'm basically try to achieve is an element to be moved at a given interval or scroll rate